# MySQL - Searching negative longitude values with BETWEEN

Tags: mysql, select, latitude-longitude

I have found many similar posts and even tried to find out how to handle negative values within MySQL, but to no avail.

I have a site that I'm using Google Maps on and as a performance enhancement I'm limiting the markers that are drawn on the map to those that are within the map boundaries.

I would like to develop a query that will work with positive or negative `latitude` and `longitude` values.

For the database:

```
latitude FLOAT( 10, 6 )
longitude FLOAT( 10, 6 )
```

The query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table` 
WHERE `latitude` BETWEEN 47.926930 AND 47.929806 
AND `longitude` BETWEEN -97.077303 AND -97.083997
```

If I drop the `BETWEEN` clause for `longitude` I get results, albeit incorrect with no `longitude` constraint.

I have tried this:

```
AND -`longitude` BETWEEN ABS( -97.077303 ) AND ABS( -97.083997 )
```

Which does work, but only for negative `longitude` values.

Do I need to check `longitude` if its negative?

Comment: When using BETWEEN you should have the lower value first, and the higher value second.  -98.083997 is lower than -97.077303, so swap the order of the two in the BETWEEN clause.

Comment: Ah yes, something simple and obvious as usual.  Thank you!  Sometimes you just need another set of eyes.  Would this be an acceptable solution? `SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE
latitude BETWEEN LEAST( 47.926930, 47.929806 ) AND GREATEST( 47.926930, 47.929806 )
AND
longitude BETWEEN LEAST( -97.077303, -97.083997 ) AND GREATEST( -97.077303, -97.083997 )`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also use the `greatest()` and `least()` functions, so you don't have to worry about the parameters. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE latitude BETWEEN least(@lat1, @lat2) AND greatest(@lat1, @lat2)
AND  longitude BETWEEN least(@lon1, @lon2) AND greatest(@lon1, @lon2)
```

Comment: I just came up with this solution! as posted above in a couple answers and comments.  Let me know what you think!  Thanks!

Comment: Accepted as this works for proper ordering of `BETWEEN` requiring the lower value before the higher value and handles the positive/negative values that latitude and longitude possess.

Answer (score 4):

`between` expects the format to be `somefield BETWEEN lowervalue AND highervalue`. Your negative longitudes have the higher/lower values switched. It should be

```
AND longitude BETWEEN -97.083997 AND -97.077303
```

negative 97.08 is actually lower than negative 97.07

Comment: Yes, thank you.  Would this work? `SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE
latitude BETWEEN LEAST( 47.926930, 47.929806 ) AND GREATEST( 47.926930, 47.929806 )
AND
longitude BETWEEN LEAST( -97.077303, -97.083997 ) AND GREATEST( -97.077303, -97.083997 )`

Comment: yeah, should do the trick nicely. `least(-1, -2)` returns `-2`, and the opposite (-1) for greatest().

Answer (score 2):

Do check how negative numbers appear on a number line. :)

```
SELECT *
FROM `table` 
WHERE `latitude` BETWEEN 47.926930 AND 47.929806 
  AND `longitude` BETWEEN -97.083997 AND -97.077303
```

Comment: I see that your solution is that of the first comment above, but not as clear.  If you would clarify a little so it is more obvious that you swapped the longitude values I will mark as accepted.  What do you think about this query to solve the issue? `SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE
latitude BETWEEN LEAST( 47.926930, 47.929806 ) AND GREATEST( 47.926930, 47.929806 )
AND
longitude BETWEEN LEAST( -97.077303, -97.083997 ) AND GREATEST( -97.077303, -97.083997 )`