# MySQL - BETWEEN operator with FLOAT(10,6) is acting like > and <, instead of >= and <=

Tags: mysql

I have a table with latitudes and longitudes of locations. I was using the BETWEEN clause successfully until I reached cases where the values being searched for where the same as those in the database. In these cases it is not returning results. Here is an example, where as:

```
SELECT 
  `Location`.`latitude`,
  `Location`.`longitude`
FROM
  `locations` AS `Location` 
WHERE `latitude` >= 40.735619 
  AND `latitude` <= 40.736561 
  AND `longitude` >= -74.033882 
  AND `longitude` <= -74.030861;
```

Returns:

```
"latitude"  "longitude"
"40.736561" "-74.033882"
"40.735619" "-74.030861"
```

If I use the BETWEEN CLAUSE (Notice I've even tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981948/mysql-searching-negative-longitude-values-with-between)):

```
SELECT   
  `Location`.`latitude`,
  `Location`.`longitude`
FROM
  `locations` AS `Location` 
WHERE `latitude` BETWEEN LEAST(40.735619, 40.736561)
  AND GREATEST(40.736561, 40.735619)
  AND `longitude` BETWEEN LEAST(- 74.033882, - 74.030861)
  AND GREATEST(- 74.030861, - 74.033882)
```

I get 0 results. Oh, whats more, if I add and/or subtract 0.000001 to each value Ex. "BETWEEN (40.735619-0.00001)" etc. If I do this it does return the two results.

Fine, I'll use >= and <= but what I don't understand is why BETWEEN is acting like > and < when in the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) its pretty clear:

> If expr is greater than or equal to min and expr is less than or equal to max, BETWEEN returns 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a decimal data type rather than a float. Equality, and hence between, for floating point values is imprecise

Comment: Thanks! Changing the data type to decimal(10,6) did the trick. So I guess what was happening is that it was rounding the values from the db up so they would be outside of the range and no longer equal? What kills me is why BETWEEN would round differently than ">= <=". Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this has to do with roundoff errors in floating point conversions. According to [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between), The expression `expr BETWEEN min AND max` is equivalent to `(expr <= max AND expr >= min)` only when all three arguments are the same type. Otherwise type conversion is applied to all arguments. It would be during this conversion that roundoff errors would occur.