# how to using query with BETWEEN with float number mysql in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I using WordPress with MySQL database
and I have a query not working with float number in 'BETWEEN' 
if I use integer number in 'BETWEEN' it's working correctly

```
$test1 = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `fnxb_os_booking_details` WHERE 
`year` = %d AND `month` = %d AND `day` = %d AND ( %d BETWEEN  `min_hour` AND 
( `max_hour` - 0.5 ) )", $yea, $mont,$da,$min_i);

$test2 = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `fnxb_os_booking_details` WHERE 
`year` = %d AND `month` = %d AND `day` = %d AND ( %d BETWEEN ( `min_hour` + 
0.5 ) AND `max_hour`  )", $yea, $mont,$da,$max_i);
```

the proplem is '0.5' . if changed to '1' it's working correctly
how can use floating number in this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the docs https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/ use the placeholder `%f`.

Also, I think it's safer to use `%f >= min_hour and %f <= (max_hour - 0.5)` rather than `BETWEEN` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11729902/366965)